# Manually Grow DBs in an Availability Group

Tags: availability-groups, database-size

When you manually grow a data file on the primary replica in an Availability Group, which of the following happens?

1. The operation gets synced to the other secondary replicas.
2. I have to manually grow the files on all replicas of cluster.

Answer (score 1):

First one.

> The operation gets synced to the other secondary replicas.

Because it is a logged operation.

Answer (score 0):

Growth and shrink both are write operations.. so it has to be performed on primary and it gets replicated to secondary node.